# keepalived BACKUP transitions to MASTER for no apparent reason

Tags: virtualbox, debian-jessie, keepalived

For testing purposes, I have brought up 2 Debian jessie VMs (using vagrant and virtualbox) and had them both running a mini web server and configures with keepalived.

The problem is that the BACKUP server transitions a few seconds after `service keepalived restart` to MASTER for no apparent reason.

I am also seeing VRRP multicast packets arriving on both servers and they look as expected. (which seems to mean that the solution suggested in [Keepalived unwanted transition to master](https://serverfault.com/questions/644949/keepalived-unwanted-transition-to-master) is not related)

The configurations files are as follows:

MASTER server:

```
global_defs {
        lvs_id tom_lvs
}

vrrp_instance tom_lvs {
        state MASTER
        interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 1
    lvs_sync_daemon_interface eth1
    priority 100
    preempt
        authentication {
                auth_type PASS
                auth_pass 1234
        }

    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.28.128.10/24
    }

        virtual_server 172.28.128.10 3000 {
                delay_loop 10
                lb_algo wlc
                lb_kind DR
                protocol TCP
                persistence_timeout 1800
                sorry_server 172.28.128.3 3000
                real_server 172.28.128.4 3000 {
                        weight 5
                        HTTP_GET {
                                url {
                                        path /index.html
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

BACKUP server:

```
global_defs {
        lvs_id tom_lvs
}

vrrp_instance tom_lvs {
        state BACKUP
        interface eth1
    virtual_router_id 2
        lvs_sync_daemon_interface eth1
    priority 96
    preempt
        authentication {
                auth_type PASS
                auth_pass 1234
        }

    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        172.28.128.10/24
    }

        virtual_server 172.28.128.10 3000 {
                delay_loop 10
                lb_algo wlc
                lb_kind DR
                protocol TCP
                persistence_timeout 1800
                sorry_server 172.28.128.3 3000
                real_server 172.28.128.3 3000 {
                        weight 5
                        HTTP_GET {
                                url {
                                        path /index.html
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

logs on the backup server that shows the transition from BACKUP to MASTER:

```
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1145]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) sending 0 priority
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Configuration is using : 62104 Bytes
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Configuration is using : 12103 Bytes
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) Entering BACKUP STATE
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Feb 14 13:22:44 jessie Keepalived_healthcheckers[1175]: Activating healthchecker for service [172.28.128.3]:3000
Feb 14 13:22:48 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) Transition to MASTER STATE
Feb 14 13:22:49 jessie Keepalived_vrrp[1176]: VRRP_Instance(tom_lvs) Entering MASTER STATE
```

and this is what I see on both machines in `tshark`

```
Capturing on 'eth1'
  1   0.000000 172.28.128.4 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 60 Announcement (v2)
  2   0.001404 172.28.128.3 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 54 Announcement (v2)
  3   1.002283 172.28.128.4 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 60 Announcement (v2)
  4   1.004130 172.28.128.3 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 54 Announcement (v2)
  5   2.004466 172.28.128.4 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 60 Announcement (v2)
  6   2.006260 172.28.128.3 -> 224.0.0.18   VRRP 54 Announcement (v2)
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question while researching a similar behaviour so I thought I'd post the answer for the benefit of anyone else who is similarly puzzled.

Both config files need to use the same value for the virtual_router_id, as this is how keepalived knows that status messages are for the same virtual router.

In the config above, they have different values, and are therefore operating independently.

Comment: Wow, this totally saved me from banging my head against my desk! thank you!